# Chart.js offine mode

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I need to create a graph in HTML page with Flask.

I've used this tutorial:
http://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2017/12/14/graphing-pretty-charts-with-python-flask-and-chartjs/

My app has to run in offline mode eventually, so instead of using:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>
```

in my HTML file, i've copied the code in `Chart.min.js` to my computer and replaced the code line with:

```
<script src="/static/Chart.min.js"> </script>
```

There is no path error. The path `/static/Chart.min.js` exists.

In the first case (online mode) the graph works perfectly, on the second case (offline) the graph isn't displayed.

What's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: are the html page and /static both in the same directory?

Comment: no, in my C:\Users\lotem\PycharmProjects\Flask i have a "static" folder, and  a "templates" folder which has the HTML in it.  but even when i use explicit path (C:\Users\lotem\PycharmProjects\Flask\static\Chart.min.js) it doesn't work

Comment: You need to use relative, not absolute paths.

Comment: Maybe try copy static folder to the templates folder.

Answer (score 2):

Write the src tag for calling the js file as

```
<script src="../static/Chart.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before,
So do this on your script tag change "Chart.min.js" to "chart.min.js". The issue there was capital letter on Chart.js although the file i have was named Chart.js but when i change it to small letter it work. Sorry for the poor english